# Extensão .pdf não baixa em download de php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Boa noite,

Eu tenho uma tabela no banco de dados que cadastra arquivos(pdf,img,png e etc...) chamada

boletos:

```
CREATE TABLE boletos ( 
 protocolo int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 boleto mediumblob NOT NULL,
 nomeBoleto varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 tipoBoleto varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (protocolo));
```

Consegui fazer o cadastro em bytes[] dos arquivos e puxar do banco e fazer o download, todos os arquivos baixam perfeitamente, somente o pdf que não baixa com a extensão dele (.pdf), ele baixa com a extensão de (todos os arquivos) e eu tenho que clicar em cima para escolher para ele abrir em pdf, alguém sabe pq isso acontece só com o pdf, meu codigo está assim:

download.php:

```
<?php
include "config.php";
// Define o tempo máximo de execução em 0 para as conexões lentas
    set_time_limit(100);

$GerParam=filter_input(INPUT_GET, "protocolo" ,FILTER_DEFAULT);
if(isset($_GET['protocolo'])){
     $protocolo = $_GET['protocolo'];
     $stat = $db->prepare("SELECT nomeBoleto,tipoBoleto,boleto FROM boletos WHERE protocolo=?");

    $stat->execute(array($_GET['protocolo']));
    $stat->bindColumn(1, $nomeBoleto, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
    $stat->bindColumn(2, $tipoBoleto, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
    $stat->bindColumn(3, $boleto, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $stat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

                header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header("Content-Type: $tipoBoleto"); 
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nomeBoleto");
                echo $boleto;


}

?>
```

Todos baixam com a extensão certa só o pdf que não...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verifique se o nome do boleto está correto, um possibilidade é do nome do boleto estar sem a extensão PDF, no `filename=$nomeBoleto`, caso o nome do boleto esteja vazio, não terá problema, entretanto se tiver nome, caso não tenha a extensão do boleto, poderá ocorrer problemas.

Sugestão de alteração de tamanho do campo **nomeBoleto** e **tipoBoleto**

```sql
CREATE TABLE boletos 
  ( 
     protocolo  INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     boleto     MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL, 
     nomeboleto VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
     tipoboleto VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (protocolo) 
  );
```

```
<?php
include "config.php";
// Define o tempo máximo de execução em 0 para as conexões lentas
set_time_limit(100);
$protocolo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "protocolo", FILTER_DEFAULT);
if (isset($protocolo)) {
    $sql = "SELECT nomeBoleto, tipoBoleto, boleto FROM boletos WHERE protocolo= :protocolo";
    $stat = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stat->bindParam(':protocolo', $protocolo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stat->execute();
    $result = $stat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($result) {
        $nomeBoleto = $result["nomeBoleto"];
        $tipoBoleto = $result["tipoBoleto"];
        $boleto = $result["boleto"];

        $extensoes_usadas = array('.jpg', '.gif', '.png','.pdf','.img');                
        if(!in_array($nomeBoleto, $extensoes_usadas) === true){
            $nomeBoleto = "";
        }

        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');            
        header("Content-Type: $tipoBoleto");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nomeBoleto");
        echo $boleto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fucionou perfeito @Oliveira, bastou alterar o campo nomeBoleto para Varchar(255) como vc sugeriu, já resolveu o problema, mto obrigado msm.. :)